# htaccess setting resets upon uploading new updates

Tags: password

Hi I am trying to set up password protected web pages with htaccess on dreamhost.com. While the panel in dreamhost allows one to set up password protection rather quickly. Once I uploaded updates to the directory, the protection is gone. How should I deal with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are overwriting the htaccess and possibly .htpasswrd files during the upload, it would be best to delete any local copies of these files before uploading.

Comment: Thanks. I downloaded these files now just in case they are overwritten during updating.